How to show training time in "Training" bar when option leave set to True in Pytorch Lightning
I have tqdmbar callback with leave=True in trainer callbacks :
pl.pytorch.callbacks.TQDMProgressBar(leave=True)

but during training it only updates epoch bars and training bar doesn't work
training process
I would like to know how to make training bar show current and left training time

Did you look at this repo showing how to customize tqdm https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/blob/master/DEMO.ipynb

@NaveedAhmed, It's tqdm, but i have a problem with tqdm bar from lightning
